# Adding image to Excel file generated by Axlsx.?

Tags: ruby, image, excel, xlsx, axlsx

I am using **Axlsx** for generating Excel file.

I need to add image to the Excel File. I have used this code :

```
ws.add_image(:image_src => '../something',:noSelect => true, :noMove => true) do |image|
  image.width=1000
  image.height=200
  image.start_at 0,0
end
```

where '**ws**' is the worksheet.

It adds the required image, but i am not able to set the '**width**' & '**height**' of the image with this code. 
Even if i give `width=2000` and `height=1000`, it does not affect the image in Excel file.

Can anybody tell , what i doing wrong.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks correct to me as well, and is inline with the example in the gem.

```
wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Image with Hyperlink") do |sheet|
  img = File.expand_path('../image1.jpeg', __FILE__)
  # specifying the :hyperlink option will add a hyper link to your image.
  # @note - Numbers does not support this part of the specification.
  sheet.add_image(:image_src => img, :noSelect => true, :noMove => true, :hyperlink=>"http://axlsx.blogspot.com") do |image|
    image.width = 7
    image.height = 6
    image.hyperlink.tooltip = "Labeled Link"
    image.start_at 2, 2
  end
end
```

There is a possibility that a bug was introduced in the version you are using.

As we discussed on #axlsx, lets try this against master on github and if it does prove to be a bug in the version you are using, I'll push out a new release.

Best,

randym

Comment: After some investigation, this is working properly in MS Excel -but not in Open Office Ubuntu - time to go digging for the differences!

Comment: for reference, OOXML spec lists: 20.5.2.14 ext (Shape Extent) which contains cx and xy properties of type ST_PositiveCoordinate