# How can I add an image to a table cell using the Axlsx gem?

Tags: ruby, excel, axlsx

I'm using the Axlsx gem to create an excel file and I'd like to add an image. I am currently able to add an image but it seems to add the image in a way that makes it float on top of other content.

I'd like it to exist within a cell. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi Ryan. Do you mean as the background of a cell, or limited to the height/width of the cell? Grab me on irc freenode#axlsx if you can. - best randym

Comment: Well mostly just so the cell resizes to the size of the image.

Comment: Cheers mate, I'll try to get an example posted here soon.

Answer (score 3):

It is an old question but we never know.

There is an answer in this post : [Adding image to Excel file generated by Axlsx.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714193/adding-image-to-excel-file-generated-by-axlsx)

You can specify the cell from which you want to put the image by using image.start_at

```
sheet.add_image(:image_src => img, :noSelect => true, :noMove => true,   :hyperlink=>"http://axlsx.blogspot.com") do |image|
  image.width = 7
  image.height = 6
  image.hyperlink.tooltip = "Labeled Link"
  image.start_at 2, 2
end
```

HTH